# Object Creation in JVM

Tags: java

```
public class B extends A{

    // code goes here
}

public class C extends B{
    public void method1(){
       C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Since C is extending B which in turn is extending A ,when I create object of C how many objects will be created in JVM .

Comment: Have you done any research in this topic?

Comment: An object from a class that extends another class doesn't need objects from the parent classes to work. It just uses the classes as a template and then creates one object from its own class.

Comment: what if it wants to access some of the variables from parent class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One object will be directly created. I say "directly" because initialization expressions or constructor code could create other objects using "new".

Creating that one C object will cause four constructor calls. Immediately before the body of C's constructor, there is an explicit or implicit call to a B constructor. Similarly, B's constructor calls an A constructor, which calls the Object constructor.

The object is a C, and is a B, and is an A, and is an Object, and by the end of the process will have been initialized as each of them.

For full gory details on this process, see [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9).

Answer (score 2):

One, of `C` type. Going to add something here, to make answer over 30 symbols long...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 1. 
Call `new C()` creates one object that indeed extends `B` that extends `A` itself, so you can use functionality inherited from B and A.